# Where can I find a web control like word's textbox?

Tags: textbox, webproject

I want to use a control like below in my web project (textbox that is editable when double clicked for example). Some suggestions?

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I found "contenteditable" for div (or other html control).

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is an editable div.</div>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Thanks